# Number of stars in Android

Tags: android

```
Code: <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:numStars="11"
        android:stepSize="1.0"
        />
```

Here is the code to display 11 stars.I want to display 11 stars in pop up in nexus 4.But 11 stars are not displayed in pop up of nexus 4.only 7 stars are displayed.And i have set the step size as 1.But it is not taking it as 1, displaying it as 0.5.If i try executing the same code in tablet,more than 11 stars are displayed.I am new to android,can u please send me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Actually rating bar doesnot work properly in android you need to customise it. the original rating bar is built on progressbar, will help you in doing this : http://www.filetolink.com/494f1f7296